# How to calculate probability of intersection

Tags: probability

I have 20 numbers between 1 and 20
order these numbers in a row

Event A is no number divisible by 4 in the first 5 places

Event B is at least one number divisible by 4 in the last 5 places.

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the probability of $P(A \cap B)$

I figured out the following:

i have two groups of numbers

$D = 4,8,12,16,20$

$E= 1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15,17,18,19$

for event A to occur I need to choose 5 numbers from group $E$ , then order the other numbers as is: $C(15,5)*5!*15!/20!$
and event B to occur is the same as to say "1- D group numbers in last five places" which is just $1-A$

for event A and B to occur at the same time there must be no $D$ group number in first 5 places, and at least one $D$ group number in last 5 places.

so for places 0,1,2,3,4 need to choose all numbers from $E$ group

$C(15,5)*5! $
then for the last 5 places, choose 1 place and choose 1 $D$ group number to put it in

$C(5,1)*C(5,1)$

and then place the remaining 14 numbers in all the different combinations
which is 14!

and S would be the number of different ways to order these numbers in a row which is 20!

so from what I understand $P(A \cap B)$ would be

$C(15,5)*5!*C(5,1)*C(5,1)*14!/20! \approx 0.322$

But my course book says that this answer is wrong,
What did I miss ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have over-counted. Specifically, if you want to count a sequence that ends with "$5\, 4\, 8\, 1\, 2$", you count it once when you select $4$ from group $D$ as the designated "at least one divisible by four in the last 5 places" (and then fill in the rest with $14!$), but you also count it again when you select $8$ from $D$ as the designated divisible-by-four element.

It is easier to compute $P(A \cap B^c)$, and then compute $P(A \cap B) = P(A) - P(A \cap B^c)$.